# Apache: insecure request sent to secure port...want to redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https, custom-errors

### Preface

Firstly:  A simply Port 80 -> Port 443 Rewrite **WILL NOT** fix this.  In almost every previous question, mail thread, forum thread, etc., I have found this was the first ignorant response and was parroted several times.

Secondly: Yes I know you cannot serve HTTP and HTTPS traffic on the same port.  **This is not that.**

### Scenario:

Apache Server hosting multiple sites via port multiplication.  Port 80 serves a public site.  Port 443 serves the secure version of that site.

Ports 7443, 8443, and 9443 each serve separate SSL-Secured sites.

If a user mistypes the URL, or is given a link that isn't valid, say http://hostname.tld:7443, they are given the following ridiculous page:

[image: Apache Bad Request error message]

Instead of the server just redirecting them over to https://hostname.tld:7443.

My Question is, how in the name of [Zeus's butthole](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0-mGNSrnh0) can you modify Apache's behavior or this error message to redirect the user automagically?

Apache is obviously serving a non-https request (to display that error message) even though it is configured for HTTPS.  It seems remarkably dumb to me to not just do the redirect by default, but I can understand why they went with the behavior they did, even if I don't agree with it.  So my question is: can you change it? They are handling the error SOMEWHERE, and with Apache being the configuration cornucopia that it is, it stands to reason there is some directive somewhere to handle this behavior, but I have been unable to find it in several hours of tinkering so far.

### Update:

I have attempted a variety of things including:

- using `ErrorDocument 400` directives to get to a CGI and a PHP script that just send `Status 301` and `Location` headers. This results in a blank page.  Using `ErrorDocument 400 https://hostname.tld:7443` simply results in that link being displayed on the page.
- Using almost every combination of `mod_rewrite` I or Google can come up with, including blanket statements that direct the site entirely; these *never* work. Literally, they do nothing. I'm surmising that Apache is kicking to the above error before even attempting to process the rewrite directives.

I can't use port-based redirects, because of the custom port use.  I can't use script-based redirects because they never get served because of the http/https mismatch.  I'm almost willing to chalk this up to a bug, or an unintended behavior, but somebody had the forethought to put a very custom error message in there, they didn't bother thinking that maybe you'd want to just cart to the URL **they are already providing**?

Comment: See the [accepted answer](http://serverfault.com/a/430986/115541) for [both ssl and non-ssl on single port](http://serverfault.com/questions/430951/both-ssl-and-non-ssl-on-single-port)

Comment: Daniel, That was one of the many questions I had found and solutions I had attempted before posting this question.  I think the problem was the PHP component, but since @hrunting's answer's update is working beautifully for me at the moment, I'm not going to sink any more time into it than I already have; at least not until I have to.

Comment: upvote for the linked video, it conveys my emotions perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is probably a bug in how Apache 2.2 and lower handles this particular circumstance.

It seems that on an SSL read `400 Bad Request` error, Apache 2.2 doesn't return the HTTP response code or headers, only the HTTP response body. I test by telnetting to port 443 and sending:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

The server immediately returns (for me):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
<blockquote>Hint: <a href="https://server.tld/"><b>https://server.tld/</b></a></blockquote></p>
</body></html>
```

Note the lack of an HTTP response code or any HTTP headers.

When I do this to an Apache 2.4 server, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 10 Feb 2013 00:47:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g
Content-Length: 462
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g Server at server.tld Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

If I setup an ErrorDocument line like you did:

```
ErrorDocument 400 https://server.tld/
```

Then I get the HTML for a 302 redirect, but again, none of the headers.  Without the 302 redirect response code and the `Location:` header, the browser won't redirect.

Try upgrading to Apache 2.4 and see if it works. I've tested and confirmed with at least Apache 2.4.3, but I haven't gone through the effort of finding exactly when this was behavior was updated. I suspect that in the large amount of work they did preparing 2.4, they corrected the undesirable behavior as a side-effect.

Relevant Apache httpd bugs:

- [44907](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44907)
- [50823](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50823)

**UPDATE**

You can force a buggy Apache to give you the behavior you want (the redirect) by having the script print out its headers (which will not be sent to the client), and then manually print out again the headers you want.  Here's a basic Perl script that works under Apache 2.2.22:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();

# this will cause Apache to handle the response properly, but is meaningless otherwise
print $q->redirect("https://localhost/");

# this actually performs the redirect
print "HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n";
print "Location: https://localhost/\r\n";
print "\r\n";

# you can do whatever you want here; this will be the HTML body
```

You should be aware that there are other reasons a 400 may be generated besides just talking to an SSL port without SSL. The easy way to determine this is to look for the `HTTPS` environment variable.  If it's set, then SSL was negotiated properly and something else is causing the 400 (don't do the double header trick if that's the case). If `HTTPS` is not set, return your redirect as above.

Comment: Holy. Crap.  Perfect Answer.  Gracias.

Comment: You know, as I read this, I think to myself, "Man, it really sucks if you have Apache 2.2 and you want this kind of redirect behavior." I'm not going to go through the effort of finding an appropriate Apache 2.4 deb (or making my own) for my Ubuntu system. I bet you can hack a solution from your PHP script. Apache's clearly just dumping the output to the client, so if you return the specific expected content, I bet you can get the behavior you're looking for without upgrading Apache. Try having your PHP script print out "HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nLocation: https://server.tld/\r\n\r\n".

Comment: The problem there is that it doesn't appear that the PHP script is getting processed.  I should note that this is current sitting on Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu Server 12.04.  And yes, it really, really sucks; especially when you note that in those bug reports, they seem to be completely set against even providing an option to just automatically do the redirect, and there doesn't appear to be much hope that 2.2 will ever be getting the fix.

Comment: And like I said up above, it just doesn't make sense to me why you go through the trouble to write that error message, rather than redirecting to secure (seriously, *why* not just redirect? the more I think about it, the less I think that is a bad idea).

Comment: Are you sure the PHP script isn't getting processed? Because you get no output instead of the standard output, I bet it is getting processed. My bet is that it *is* getting processed, it's just not dumping out exactly the right data that's necessary (using PHP function calls probably assume that the web server is going to do the "right thing" which it isn't in this case). I bet if the header content were output as the body instead of normal headers, it would work.

Comment: Technically, it *is* a 400 bad request. The server can't know exactly what the client was doing. You might redirect them to `server.tld` when they were trying to reach `otherserver.tld` which would have been served properly if HTTPS would have been used with SNI. You just don't know, and the server has no way of knowing. Every web server does pretty much the same thing (although they get the response code and headers right).

Comment: Wow great bug! Great find! I wonder if this is different with SNI, since SNI allows the request to be read before the SSL Handshake.

Comment: I don't think so. In Apache, it's basically bailing when the SSL context can't be established, and when it kicks it back, the information related to the SSL context (which is where any SNI information would be) is lost.

Comment: I don't disagree that *is* a 400 Bad Request.  But with almost *every other freaking error message/status/code* I can dictate what Apache should do.  Here, in a case where that ability is, in my eyes, paramount, they kneecap you with a lame message, and don't even handle it properly so that you can't override it.

Comment: I have grepped the entire file system looking for the text of that bloody message to see if I can where they are leeching it from, on the off chance I could inject a `<javascript` tag and get lucky with hacking redirection that way, but thus far, no dice. Nothing about this seems to be handled in a way that follows the otherwise pretty rigid Apache awesomeness...

Comment: I added a comment to the [50823 bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50823), just to put my thoughts on the record there. The bug is still open, so perhaps hope still exists...

Comment: I added an update to the answer that should do what you need it to do.

Comment: So I see, thanks!  I'll try to get it tested later today / this evening and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Works beautifully man.  Dumped that into a `redirect.pl` in the `cgi-bin` and set up the corresponding `ErrorDocument 400`.  If I could accept this twice I totally would.  Thanks so much for your help, and kudos for being a better Apache Ninja than me :)

Comment: No problem. That was a fun problem to work on.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this with mod-rewrite.  Set a rule to match anything.  See this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190661/mod-rewrite-how-to-redirect-a-mistyped-pretty-url)

Comment: Nope, I already tried that, it doesn't work. Its like it doesn't even get to the ModRewrite steps because its hitting the http/https mismatch first.

Comment: Hrm so I assume you have started from the top of you apache config file and worked your way down to see what it is calling

Comment: I have practically memorized the entire `sites-available` directory.  Even if you just redirect it to nonsense, or redirect it to a different site, different port, etc., it just keeps loading that 400 Bad Request.