# Apache, redirect a client instead of showing HTTP/HTTPS error

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, http

If a web admin configures an HTTPS/SSL vhost on a custom port (e.g. 4433) and a browser connects to that vhost but using HTTP (http://vhost:4433), is there any way to configure apache to rather issue a redirect to the browser, sending it to HTTPS (https://vhost:4433), instead of displaying the well-known error:

> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server
> could not understand.
>  Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an
> SSL-enabled server port.
>   Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access
> this URL, please.

Comment: Relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/477236/apache-insecure-request-sent-to-secure-port-want-to-redirect

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can get the behavior you want by setting something like:

```
ErrorDocument 400 https://vhost:4433/
```

Source: [Apache: insecure request sent to secure port...want to redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/477236/apache-insecure-request-sent-to-secure-port-want-to-redirect)